# iTunesConnect refuses application icon - Failed to create an app icon

Tags: ios, icons, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload the icon to Appstore, but it gives my back `Failed to create an app icon`

I read that the app icon is not allowed to have rounded corners, but does that mean that my icon is a rectangle and has not rounded corners or does my icon has rounded corners in de picture itself.

I am trying this for over a day so please be kind and all help is great!

I'm using Safari.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Firefox if you are not yet doing it - it was not working on Chrome sometimes.

Comment: You can try posting a bug to Apple, but that was randomly not working for people with different browser - with no rule behind it :)